# Declaring interfaces in GoLang with array symbol

Tags: go, interface

I have seen interfaces defined like:

```
type MyInterface interface{
   Method()
}
```

and

```
type MyInterface []interface{
   Method()
}
```

What is the difference in these two definitions?

Comment: The first is an interface type, the second is a slice type whose element type is interfacs. Like `type Ints []int` is a slice of ints, `type Ifaces []interface{...` is a slice of interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The first is defining an `interface` with a method of `Method()`, while the second is defining the a `slice` of `interface`. The statement utilizes the form of *type literal* and can be interepted as:

```
type MyInterface [](interface{
   Method()
})
```

Where `interface{...}` here is a *type literal*. Which has the same effect of

```
type I = interface{
   Method()
}
type MyInterface []I
```

See more on *type literal*: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types

Note: `MyInterface` would be a very bad name in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you create

```
type Iface interface {
    Age() uint
    Name() string
}

type SliceIface []interface {
    Age() uint
    Name() string
}

// then SliceIface and []Iface has the same behaviour
```

so you could say

```
type SliceIface []Iface
```

Have a look at following code

https://play.golang.org/p/DaujSDZ8p-N

Comment: Interestingly though, if you exchange `SliceIface` with `[]Iface` on line 66, it won't compile.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it behaves like `[]Iface`. By the functional site, it is the same. But you cannot say to compiler that `[]Iface` and `SliceIface` are the same, because both are declared as independent interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is an interface declaration with a method `method()` declared in it.

```
type MyInterface interface{
   Method()
}
```

The second is that a variable with type []interface{} is not an interface! It is a slice whose element type happens to be interface{}

```
type MyInterface []interface{
   Method()
}
```

Plus, a variable with type []interface{} has a specific memory layout, known at compile time.

Comment: Any link to more details on memory layout? I'd be interested to check more details on that. Thanks.

Comment: Each interface{} takes up two words (one word for the type of what is contained, the other word for either the contained data or a pointer to it). As a consequence, a slice with length N and with type []interface{} is backed by a chunk of data that is N*2 words long.

This is different than the chunk of data backing a slice with type []MyType and the same length. Its chunk of data will be N*sizeof(MyType) words long.

The result is that you cannot quickly assign something of type []MyType to something of type []interface{}; the data behind them just look different.